# Convertir un xml en un string

Tags: c#, xml

Tengo publicado un servicio web (soap) con WCF, el cual recepciona un tipo de dato compuesto MFN_M02CONTENT.
necesito generar un log en un archivo de texto plano, que me registre los mensajes recibidos.

mi problema es, que al convertir el dato del tipo `MFN_M02CONTENT` a `string`, me guarda solo el namespace del tipo de dato `MiProyecto.HL7.MFN_M02CONTENT`, y no el xml con los tags del mensaje.

el tipo de datos `MFN-M02CONTENT` esta definido de la siguiente manera:

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName = "MFN_M02.CONTENT", Namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v2xml")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("MFN_M02", Namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v2xml", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class MFN_M02CONTENT
    {

        private MSHCONTENT mSHField;

        private SFTCONTENT[] sFTField;

        private MFICONTENT mFIField;

        private MFN_M02MF_STAFFCONTENT[] mFN_M02MF_STAFFField;

        /// <comentarios/>
        [DataMember]
        public MSHCONTENT MSH
        {
            get
            {
                return this.mSHField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.mSHField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <comentarios/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SFT")]
        [DataMember]
        public SFTCONTENT[] SFT
        {
            get
            {
                return this.sFTField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.sFTField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <comentarios/>
        [DataMember]
        public MFICONTENT MFI
        {
            get
            {
                return this.mFIField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.mFIField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <comentarios/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("MFN_M02.MF_STAFF")]
        [DataMember]
        public MFN_M02MF_STAFFCONTENT[] MFN_M02MF_STAFF
        {
            get
            {
                return this.mFN_M02MF_STAFFField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.mFN_M02MF_STAFFField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Los subtipos no los pongo, porque es demasiado extensa la definicion..

como debería transformar este tipo de mensaje XML para que quede como texto?

Update: Pongo aca la funcion donde recibo los datos

```
    public MFK_M01CONTENT Get_MFN_M02(MFN_M02CONTENT MFN_M02_Data)
{
    try
    {
        string Data = MFN_M02_Data.ToString();

        // si recibimos el dato, lo grabamos en un archivo de texto plano para ver que me trajo
        string Archivo = @"C:\LogXml\MFN_M02CONTENT.txt";
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Archivo);
        file.WriteLine(Data);
        file.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Muestramos como es que estas guardando los datos

Comment: Hola, gtracias por responder. puse al final del post la funcion sonse recibo el dato e intento generar el log convirtiendo el mensaje a string.

Comment: El problema es que no puedes simplemente poner `ToString`. Eso lo unico que te va a devolver es el tipo del objeto. En realidad tu pregunta no es correcta, ya que lo que quieres convertir no es XML, sino un objeto de tipo `MFN_M02CONTENT`.Una posible solución yo creo que sería que sobrecargaras el método `ToString()` para que te devolviera los datos de la clase formateados como tu quieras.

Comment: Como dice @Pikoh, tienes que serializar a la forma en como desees. El hecho de que se utilize esa clase como representacion de xml, no significa que te mostrar el XML como string.

Comment: gracias a todos por los comentarios, me aclararon bastante mis dudas.. esta claro que teno que seguir estudiando estos temas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias soluciones para tu problema, pero como te explico en mi comentario lo que quieres convertir a `string` no es XML, sino un objeto de tipo `MFN_M02CONTENT`. Una posible solución sería sobrecargar el método `ToString` de tu clase para que serialice tu objeto. Sería algo asi:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
    serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, this);
    return stringwriter.ToString();
}
```

De esa manera, `MFN_M02_Data.ToString();` retornaría el objeto serializado.

Comment: muchas gracias, funciono perfectatemte